# HTML5/Javascript web audio api - SoundManager

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to create a sound manager for a simple game, which I know is not necessary for this application but for the learning experience I'm doing so.
I've tried a few different approaches with no real success yet. Below is my current attempt.
I believe my main problem is with my XML request as with each attempt my file does not seem to load.

any advice on where I'm going wrong or what i should do differently would be very much appreciated.

My audio manager(far from complete but should load and play a sound?)

```
var audioctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
function AudioManager(totalsounds) {
this.ctx = audioctx;
this.sounds = {};
this.totalSounds = totalsounds;
this.loaded = 0;
this.masterGain = this.ctx.createGain(); // master gain control
this.masterGain.connect(this.ctx.destination);
this.loadSound = function(name) {
    this.sounds[name] = new Sound(name, this);
    console.log("sound Loaded?");
};
this.play = function(name) {
    if(this.sounds[name] !== undefined)
    {
        this.sounds[name].source.start(0);
        console.log("playing?");
    } else
    {
        console.log(name + " - sound not found!");
    }
};
};
```

sound objects created by the manager and stored within.(code seems to never load file)

```
function Sound(name, audiomanager){
this.manager = audiomanager;
this.source;
this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
this.request.open('GET', name, true);
this.request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
console.log(" i think code stops here");
this.request.onload = function() {
    this.manager.loaded += 1;
    console.log("loaded?");
    this.manager.ctx.decodeAudioData(this.request.response).then(function(buffer){
        this.source = manager.ctx.createBufferSource();
        this.source.buffer = buffer;
        this.source.connect(manager.masterGain);
    });
};
    this.request.send();
}
```

much later i try to test it out as follows.

```
var audio = new AudioManager(1);
audio.loadSound("test.mp3");
if(audio.loaded == audio.totalSounds){setTimeout(game, 50);}
function game() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setInterval(function() {
        if(buttonDown[5])
        {
            audio.play("test.mp3");
        }
    },100);
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to `send()` your xhr request. But `this` in xhr's `onload` refers to the xhr request itself, not to your `Sound` object. (you'll get the same in `decodeAudioData` callback btw). So you'll probably have an error raised in your dev-tools console.

Comment: thanks. makes sense with the this problem. my last attempt used a self variable instead, guess ill  go back to that. as for send it was there i must have just failed with my copy and paste. I'll edit it back in so that doesn't keep getting the blame.

Comment: Note: Java != JavaScript ..so the [tag:javasound] tag is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: sorry. will read properly before adding next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it working. If anyone finds this while looking for answers to a similar problem, here is a working (though still very rough and ugly) version.

```
var audioctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
function AudioManager(totalsounds) {
this.ctx = audioctx;
this.sounds = {};
this.totalSounds = totalsounds;
this.loaded = 0;
this.masterGain = this.ctx.createGain(); // master gain control
this.masterGain.connect(this.ctx.destination);
this.loadSound = function(name, delaytime) {
    this.sounds[name] = new Sound(name, this, delaytime);
    console.log("sound Loaded?");
};
this.play = function(name) {
    var buffer = this.ctx.createBufferSource();
    if(this.sounds[name] !== undefined && !this.sounds[name].delayed)
    {
        buffer.buffer = this.sounds[name].source;
        buffer.connect(this.masterGain);
        buffer.start(0);
        console.log("playing?");
        this.sounds[name].delaySet();
    } else if(this.sounds[name].delayed)
    {
        console.log("audio delayed = " + this.sounds[name].delayed);
    } else
    {
        console.log(name + " - sound not found!");
    }

};
};
function Sound(name, audiomanager, delaytime){
this.manager = audiomanager;
this.source;
this.delay = delaytime;
this.delayed = false;
var self = this;
this.delaySet = function(){
    console.log("RESET");
    self.delayed = true;
    setTimeout(function(){self.delayed = false;}, self.delay);
};
this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
this.request.open('GET', name, true);
this.request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
console.log("stops here");
this.request.onload = function() {
    self.manager.loaded += 1;
    console.log("loaded?");

self.manager.ctx.decodeAudioData(self.request.response).then(function(buffer){
        self.source = buffer;
    });
};
this.request.send();
}
```

with a slightly modified call after adding delay feature.(not part of the actual solution)

```
var audio = new AudioManager(1);
audio.loadSound("test.mp3", 1500);
var a = setInterval(function() {
if(audio.loaded >= audio.totalSounds){setTimeout(game, 50); clearInterval(a);}
}, 100);
function game() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setInterval(function() {
        if(buttonDown[5])
        {
            console.log("SOUND");
            audio.play("test.mp3");
        }
    },100);
```